# Highcharts svg convert to png with server

Tags: svg, highcharts, png

I use high charts to convert charts to images.

Please give me an answer. TT

I used base64 because I needed to save the image on the server, but I had

difficulty using the highcharts api.

I succeeded in converting the svg of the chart to base64.

However, there was an error converting base64 to png.

Base64 is normally encoded but does not convert to png.

```
Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts) {
        var svgArr = [],
            top = 0,
            width = 0;

        Highcharts.each(charts, function (chart) {

            var svg = chart.getSVG();
            svg = svg.replace(
                '<svg',
                '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" '
            );
            svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
            top += chart.chartHeight;
            width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);
            svgArr.push(svg);

            var b64 = btoa(svg);
            var data = "bin_data=" + b64;
            alert("end")

             $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                    url: "ImgSave",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){
                    alert('success');
                                            } 
                    }); 

        });

        return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width +
            '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
            svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
    };

    Highcharts.exportCharts = function (charts, options) {

        // Merge the options
        options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

        // Post to export server
        Highcharts.post(options.url, {
            filename: options.filename || 'chart',
            type: options.type,
            width: options.width,
            svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
        });
    };

    $("#imagesave").click(function() {

        Highcharts.exportCharts([chart]);

    });
```

//java

```
        System.out.println("start");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");

        String strFile = req.getParameter("bin_data");
        strFile = strFile.replace(" ","+"); //
        System.out.println("***"+strFile);

        byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(strFile);

        try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("path"+sdf.format(new Date()).toString()+".png")){
                stream.write(decoded);
            }
}
```

Attach the code. Is there a way?

Perhaps,
Is there a base64 encoding of the code of a high chart?

If possible, I would appreciate, for example, to explain the code.

Thank you for reading.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Highcharts exporting supports PNG and you could [set up your own exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server).

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, because SVG must be translated and interpreted before it can be stored in PNG or other image formats.

You can use `org.apache.batik` to achieve the conversion effect, but at present SVG conversion procedures are limited, I am also doing this piece of free can be studied together.

Comment: he is not your brother.